# Android Youtube version less that 4.2.16

Tags: android, youtube-api

The minimum Youtube App. version required to be installed on a device to use the Youtube API is 4.2.16

To get the youtube app. version installed on a device:

```
String version = YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionName(getContext());
```

Thats could return as known a three numbers separeted by dots. How can I check if the returned version number is less than 4.2.16. Which is obviously not an integer and not a floating point number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepted for the ##Original answer:

### Original answer:

Well, this may not be the easiest way, but you can do something like this:

First split the string at the `.`'s:

```
String[] partsOfVersion = version.split("\\.");
```

Then convert each part into an `int`:

```
int first = partsOfVersion.length>0 ? Integer.parseInt(partsOfVersion[0]) : 0;
int second = partsOfVersion.length>1 ? Integer.parseInt(partsOfVersion[1]) : 0;
int third = partsOfVersion.length>2 ? Integer.parseInt(partsOfVersion[2]) : 0;
```

Then you can just use an `if` statement to check if they're above `4.2.16`:

```
if((first == 4 && second == 2 && third >= 16) || (first == 4 && second >== 3) || first >= 5) {
    ...
}
```

And if you want to check if it's less than that, just use an `else` statement after that `if` statement.

That *should* work, I haven't tested it though.

### Added:

Someone (@JeroenVannevel) pointed out to me that there's an easier way to do this.

First remove all occurrences of `.`:

```
version = version.replace(".", "");
```

Then convert the string to an `int`:

```
int versionInt = Integer.parseInt(version);
```

And finally, check if the number is greater than or equal to (or less than if you want incompatible devices) `4216`:

```
if(versionInt >= 4216) {
    ...
}
```

Also, you might want to check if `version` is empty or not before starting.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel answer is buggy. what if the next version of Youtube is 5.0. converting it to int gives 50 which is less than 4.2.16 = 4216

Comment: that also stand for you original answer. null pointer exception will occur in int third = Integer.parseInt(partsOfVersion[2]); for version 5.0

Comment: @hasan Yes, for the null pointer part you could just check if there's a third digit, if so continue, if not don't parse that digit and don't use it in comparisons. Also, for your first question you could add trailing zeroes if the length of `version` is less than 4.

Answer (score 2):

the answer to your problem is very simple, as you see from AndroidManifest.xml file to 
YouTube 4.2.16 android apk I found this line .

```
<manifest android:versionCode="4216" android:versionName="4.2.16" package="com.google.android.youtube" ...>
```

so to check if app  you need to do to check if the VersionCode biger than  int (4216) by Public methods

```
getInstalledYouTubeVersionCode(Context context)
```

for more info visit [YouTubeIntents](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents) Reference Guide.

In final you can use this ready check

```
    if(YouTubeIntents.isYouTubeInstalled(getActivity()) && YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionCode(getActivity())>4216){
```

//do what you want whit YouTubeIntents
}else {
//Ask user to install the last youtube app .

}

I hope this answer help you.

Comment: "Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API."

So it should be >= 4216 so you don't exclude the people exactly on version 4.2.16

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class for precisely this purpose, maybe it could be useful.

```
public class Version implements Comparable<Version>
{
    public final int Major;
    public final int Minor;
    public final int Build;
    public final int Revision;

    public Version(int major, int minor)
    {
        this(major, minor, 0);
    }

    public Version(int major, int minor, int build)
    {
        this(major, minor, build, 0);
    }

    public Version(int major, int minor, int build, int revision)
    {
        Major = major;
        Minor = minor;
        Build = build;
        Revision = revision;
    }

    public Version(String str)
    {
        int major = 0;
        int minor = 0;
        int build = 0;
        int revision = 0;

        if (Strings.hasValue(str))
        {
            String[] parts = str.split("\\.");

            if (parts.length > 0)
                major = parseInt(parts[0]);
            if (parts.length > 1)
                minor = parseInt(parts[1]);
            if (parts.length > 2)
                build = parseInt(parts[2]);
            if (parts.length > 3)
                revision = parseInt(parts[3]);
        }

        Major = major;
        Minor = minor;
        Build = build;
        Revision = revision;
    }

    private static int parseInt(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s", Major, Minor, Build, Revision);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (Major == 0 && Minor == 0 && Build == 0 && Revision == 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Version another)
    {
        if (another == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        int[] thisV = new int[] { Major, Minor, Build, Revision };
        int[] otherV = new int[] { another.Major, another.Minor, another.Build, another.Revision };

        for (int i = 0; i < thisV.length; i++)
        {
            if (thisV[i] < otherV[i])
                return -1;
            else if (thisV[i] > otherV[i])
                return +1;
            // else, loop to consider less significant parts.
        }

        return 0; // All equal.
    }
}
```